# overpass 'around' module runs very slow

Tags: typescript, performance, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using the 'around' module with overpass-api (based on OSM). The goal of this function is to get all the locations within a certain radius of the given coordinates.

I tried this both using python and TypeScript, provided below is my code for typescript.

The problem is that this runs sometimes for over 20seconds! And I am sure I did not surpass any usage limitations, since I was testing it all manually (max. 15 API calls).

The slowness occurs both in Typescript and Python, so its not a code issue (imo)

```
async function searchNearbyFeatures(latitude: number, longitude: number, radius: number): Promise<any[]> {
    const overpassUrl = 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter';
    const query = `
      [out:json];
      (
        node(around:${radius},${latitude},${longitude});
        way(around:${radius},${latitude},${longitude});
        relation(around:${radius},${latitude},${longitude});
      );
      out center;
    `;
    const params = {
        data: query,
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(overpassUrl, { params });
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = response.data;
            return data.elements as any[];
        } else {
            console.error('Error occurred:', response.statusText);
            return [];
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        return [];
    }
}
```

example input:

```
latitude = 40.71162073116427 
longitude = -74.00619658336431
radius = 20  // meters
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue? For example, I tried to look at [the source code of overpass](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/blob/master/src/overpass_api/statements/around.cc) to use directly OSM, but this seems like a difficult thing to figure out how to do. 
I also did not find a 'native' way to do this using only OSM.

Is there already a solution for this problem or can you suggest how to resolve the speed issue?

Comment: This is a public, free service. It doesn't provide any assurances regarding performance or even reliability. Feel free to install your own Overpass API instance.

Comment: Likely that’s been a temporary issue only due to server load. Instead of around you could also use bounding boxes, like described in the overpass documentation.